# Giving error for wrong return type in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void factor(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
    return;
    for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++){
        while(n%i==0){
            printf(i);
            n=n/i;
        }
    }
    if(n>1)
    {
    return n;
    }
}

int main(){
    factor(10);
}
```

Error:
return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
16 |     return n;
|            ^

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int factor(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
    return;
    for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++){
        while(n%i==0){
            printf(i);
            n=n/i;
        }
    }
    if(n>1)
    {
    return n;
    }
}

int main(){
    factor(10);
}

Comment: For int , showing this error:

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   18 | }
      | ^

Comment: your function's return value is void, it cannot return a value int. Change your return type.

Comment: You can spam your own question as much as you like - but - what is your question? I vote for this question to be removed. I'll help noone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that your function `factor` has a return type of `void` but it actually returns an `int` object.

To **solve** this, you should match the return type of the function `factor` with what you're actually returning from inside the function as shown below.

**Secondly** you should also take care of the situation when none of the conditions(like `if`) are satisfied by adding appropriate return statements as shown below:

```
int factor(int n) //VOID CHANGED TO INT HERE
{
    if(n<=1)
    return 0; //CHANGED RETURN TO RETURN 0 HERE
    for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++){
        while(n%i==0){
            //printf(i);
            n=n/i;
        }
    }
    if(n>1)
    {
    return n;
    }
    return 0;//ADDED RETURN HERE for the case if none of the if are satisfied and control flow reaches here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type shoud not be void but int.

Comment: And instead of ```return;``` you should use ```return 0;```

Comment: int gives warning:

Comment: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   18 | }
      | ^

Comment: Are you taking a test live?

Comment: This is a whole lot of mess in the code. We should only return _after_ all desired code has been executed. You've done it at the very beginning. Also consider using else if instead of simple ifs.